# Display output in message window in Turbo C

Tags: c, turbo-c++, turbo-c

How can I print my output in Message window of Turbo-C ?

Example:

[image: defaut programming style]

By default, the output is generated on the output screen as

[image: default output]

**but how do I print output in the Message Window(where errors are displayed) ?**

[image: Message Window]

I am using TURBO-C version 3.0 and DOSBox version 0.74.

Comment: Try `fprintf(stderr, "Hello")`

Comment: Oh my!  I haven't seen Turbo C since the 90s.  I can't remember if you can direct program output to the Message window.  Perhaps there's a built-in 'Trace' command.  Otherwise, I was about to recommend trying with standard error, but got beaten to it by Daniel =)

Comment: Me too. I haven't seen Turbo C and I think this question is asked by somebody from the past

Comment: fprintf did not work :( .

Comment: can you share some knowledege here ? @alk

Answer (score 0):

You can try tracing your code by opening the watch window ... steps for the process is

1. click window
2. click watch
3. press f7 keep pressing f7 multiple times to trace through each line in your code .

Comment: not talking about the watch window i know what watch window is